# How can I compile nginx with lua?

Tags: nginx, lua

I have to use lua with nginx. I have heard that have to compile "nginx with lua". What is meant by "compile nginx with lua"? How can I "compile" nginx with lua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua support in nginx is a module which is not compiled by default. The easiest way to obtain it is to use the [OpenResty](http://openresty.org/) distribution. You can also [compile it into your nginx](https://github.com/chaoslawful/lua-nginx-module#installation) like a [regular nginx module](http://wiki.nginx.org/3rdPartyModules).